# Wrong ruby version detected on mac after brew installing

Tags: ruby, homebrew

When I run

```
ruby -v
```

i get `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`

this is after installing the latest version of ruby with `brew install ruby`

tried uninstalling and reinstalling and same thing. How can I get the latest version of ruby? If relevent, I need it for `gem install bundler` which requires a later version.

Comment: Did you run `brew update` before `brew install`?. Anyways you might take a look to Rbenv or RVM.

Comment: Big fan of rbenv and rvm if you're in a position to use a Ruby version management tool.  Will also shout out asdf and anyenv for managing versions of multiple languages all at once!

Comment: Run `brew info ruby` and follow the instructions it gives you at the bottom, then start a new shell session. Does it help?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

Answer (score 0):

This is how to update your ruby version steps

To check what your ruby in now

```
$Ruby -v
```

Update it to ruby version 2.3.7

```
$rvm list known
$rvm install 2.3.7
$rvm use 2.3.7 --default
$gem install bundler
```

Let me know if does that help!

Comment: This assumes OP is using rvm, which I imagine might not be true from the post.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew can help you with this.

First, run `brew info ruby` (in my case, I wanted to specify a specific version, so I ran `brew info ruby@2.7`.)

It showed this output (some removed for clarity):

```
License: Ruby
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: libyaml ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔
==> Caveats
ruby@2.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have ruby@2.7 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find ruby@2.7 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/include"
```

I then edited my `.zshrc` file (if you're using bash, you may need to use .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc) and added this:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

I opened a new tab in my terminal and ran `ruby --version`:

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.7.7p221 (2022-11-24 revision 168ec2b1e5) [arm64-darwin21]
```

(I didn't need the additional instructions for compilers, but you might if you do compiling with C++ or cmake.)

Done!